# NSIS recursive file copy using CopyFiles rather than File command

Tags: installation, nsis

For an NSIS installer I have been using this command:

```
SetOutPath $INSTDIR\data
File /r /x *.svn data\newTerrainTiled
```

to copy my data files into the executable itself.  I now have a larger data set that has outgrown the maximum size of the installer executable.  I tried to change my code to this:

```
SetOutPath $INSTDIR\data
CopyFiles /r $EXEDIR\data\newTerrainTiled
```

But obviously CopyFiles does not have a recursive flag.  I realize I could create the subdirectories of the newTerrainTiled folder one by one and then used CopyFiles with the wildcard (*) character.  I wanted to know if someone has already come up with a recursive method of copying using CopyFiles in place of File for when data sets become large.

Thanks.

Comment: The CopyFiles syntax is: CopyFiles [flags] <source> <destination>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- The File instruction packs files **from the system you are compiling on** into the installer.
- CopyFiles copies files and/or folders from a to b **on the end users system!** (That is, both the source and destination is on the end users system and the source files actually have to exist before you copy)

CopyFiles can copy a directory (with all files and subfolders) but in your case it would only be useful if the data directory was on a CD/DVD along with the installer.

Other alternatives are:

- Put the data files in a external archive (zip etc) and use one of the NSIS plugins to extract.
- Append the data to the end of the generated installer and extract that ("unlimited" file size)

Comment: I understand what the CopyFiles syntax is.

I understand that CopyFiles requires files to exist on the end uer's system already.

The newTerrainTiled has a great many subdirectories and they are editied enough that creating a zip archive or storing a bunch of CreateDirectory/CopyFiles commands in the install script is problematic.

I don't know how to append the data to the end of the generated installer nor how to extract it.

I was mostly wondering: has somebody written a macro or function that does a recursive CopyFiles?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot.  CopyFiles already will do a recursive copy, as you said -- somehow missed that on my first read.